# Device specific constraints Xcode 13

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I'm having some issues setting up device specific constraints. I know how to use Vary for Traits, but it isn't advanced enough for what I need to do.

Basically, my app displays perfectly fine on any notched device (eg. iPhone 11), but fails to space correctly on any non notched device (eg. iPhone 6s).

Do you know any way to achieve what I need? Thank you!

Comment: What's your exact problem? Do you have screenshots or code you can share?

Comment: I'm building a simple camera app. I have the live preview constrained to align perfectly with the buttons over and above the view (both in landscape and portrait). On a 6s iPhone though, the view covers the top buttons and I cannot resize it to be smaller only on that device.

Answer (score 0):

It tends to be better practice to use constraints that are universal. If I understand correctly, a good solution would be to add an equal height constraint to the view in order to make sure that a portion of the screen is always available for the buttons. I added the following constraints:
[list of constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58HA5.png)

In the view controller the result is this:
[view controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5Qvs.png)

And the live preview for notched and not notched devices is this:
[notched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK9uU.png)
[not notched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPijA.png)

Alternatively, if you are building a camera app, you can use the object 'UIImagePickerController' with the 'sourceType' attribute set to '.camera' which will create a pop-up view controller displaying the camera app.

Comment: Please edit your message and put the images inline, that makes the reading easier

Comment: I can't unfortunately. It says I need a higher reputation.